# parcel build static/index.html × Build failed. Error: No transformers found for index.x-handlebars-template

Tags: express, optimization, build, handlebars.js, parceljs

I am trying to build an application with handlebars templating and express server. index.html file has all the handlebar templating within script tags with mentioned type="text/x-handlebars-template"

When I run "parcel build static/index.html", build is failing with following error message.
"Build failed. Error: No transformers found for index.x-handlebars-template."

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this myself recently. StackOverflow does not allow me to comment yet, so I had to post this as an answer. The following `.parcelrc` configuration will *work around* this error:

```json
{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
  "transformers": {
    "*.x-handlebars-template": ["@parcel/transformer-inline-string"]
  }
}
```

Note that the `x-handlebars-template` will not be minimised within the resulting HTML file. I'll keep you posted if I ever come across an *actual* solution.